# discord.js user id to username

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making a bot and I am trying to make it happen that every time a person uses a command it will log it in the console, this is my code.

```
            console.log(message.author ++ ,`used the command 'come'`);
```

(the command is come)
every time I do this it logs the user's id, and I want it to send the username (user#6969)

Comment: What's the `++` for? Are you trying to concatenate?

Answer (score 2):

```js
console.log(message.author.tag, " used the command 'come'");
// prints: username#1234 used the command 'come'
```